# Is it possible to have "Stickiness" expire after a certain time limit, or is there any workaround for this?

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I have a client who would like to mark new entries as Sticky, but have the Stickiness only last for 90 days, to give new entries a push and get them promoted initially.

They could un-sticky the entry after 90 days manually, but they have thousands of entries which will make this hard to maintain.

In the same way that you can set an Expiry Date, is it possible to set a Sticky Expiry Date, or can you think of any clean way to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about just using the Expiry Date?

In the featured articles section of the site, use the following tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries show_expired="no"}
```

which will only show articles which haven't expired.

Then in the archive section (where all articles are shown) use this:

```
{exp:channel:entries show_expired="yes"}
```

which will included expired entries in the list too as well as unexpired ones.

You could get them to set the expiration date to be 3 months after the publish date when they publish an article.

Alternatively, you could write an extension that uses the `entry_submission_start` hook to add an expiration date based on a globally set time period.

Looking on Devot-ee, there appears to be an abandoned extension, [Auto Expire](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/auto-expire), that does this but it would need probably updating for the latest version of EE.